# Countif, sumif, or any other relevant formulas

Tags: count, sum, return-value

If same name appears multiple times then,
for 1st time it should sum and return the value
but for next times it should exclude the 1st value of same name and same range and sum remaining values
And should continue the same in whole sheet

Same as above
And also the formula should be between 2 sheets